# get claims of entity wikidata by wbgetentities search label

Tags: api, request, wikidata, wikidata-api

I was wondering what the simplest way is to get data from wikidata by labels searching like :

```
API_ENDPOINT = "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php"
query = "cobalt-70"
params = {
    'action': 'wbsearchentities',
    'format': 'json',
    'language': 'en',
    'type':'item',
    'search': query
}
r = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, params = params)


Output:

{'searchinfo': {'search': 'cobalt-70'}, 'search': [{'id': 'Q18844865', 'title': 'Q18844865', 'pageid': 20388165, 'repository': 'local', 'url': '//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q18844865', 'concepturi': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q18844865', 'label': 'cobalt-70', 'description': 'isotope of cobalt', 'match': {'type': 'label', 'language': 'en', 'text': 'cobalt-70'}}, {'id': 'Q18880148', 'title': 'Q18880148', 'pageid': 20426734, 'repository': 'local', 'url': '//www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q18880148', 'concepturi': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q18880148', 'label': 'cobalt-70m', 'description': 'isotope of cobalt', 'match': {'type': 'label', 'language': 'en', 'text': 'cobalt-70m'}}], 'success': 1}
```

So I want to get statements with the same url request by using "claims" in action params.
For example:

```
"P2114": [
                    {
                        "mainsnak": {
                            "snaktype": "value",
                            "property": "P2114",
                            "hash": "6f767f24024d5e0045afcf4d49d1a1b4dbc88fe5",
                            "datavalue": {
                                "value": {
                                    "amount": "+0.5",
                                    "unit": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q11574",
                                    "upperBound": "+0.68",
                                    "lowerBound": "+0.32"
                                },
                                "type": "quantity"
                            },
                            "datatype": "quantity"
                        },
....
```

Thank you!